# Google app script passing of variables into a trigger function

Tags: javascript

Google app script creating a trigger and passing variables to it

My code creates google forms and I want it so that everytime a form is submitted a email is sent to me, if I initialise it like my createformtrigger in the loop, it will just send me an email even though there have been no responses to my form yet
Everytime the onFormSubmit trigger triggers, the variables return as undefined here is my code below

```
function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
}

function sendEmailNotification4(formName, responseSheetUrl) {
  const targetEmail = "aldenrequeza@gmail.com";
  const emailSubject = formName + " New Form Response";
  const emailBody = "A new response has been submitted. Link to response: " + responseSheetUrl;
  MailApp.sendEmail(targetEmail, emailSubject, emailBody);
}

function createFormTrigger(formId, formName, responseSheetUrl) {
  var form = FormApp.openById(formId);

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmailNotification4')
    .withUserObject(formName, responseSheetUrl)
    .forForm(form)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}

function setQuestionAnswer4() {
  var firebaseUrl = "https://form-creation-9a11f-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app";
  var firebaseSecret = "Ovj0JDfOB4VosNSrwEROJc4yzGoiA1YG7CbCY5Kq";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl, firebaseSecret);
  var quizzes = base.getData("quizzes");

  // Loop through the quizzes
  for (var quizName in quizzes) {
    var quiz = quizzes[quizName];

    // Check if the quiz has the "status" property set to true
    if (quiz.hasOwnProperty("status") && quiz.status === false) {
      const form = FormApp.create(quizName); // open the existing form

      var header = quiz.header;
      var description = quiz.description;
      var extractedname = quizName;

      form.setIsQuiz(true);
      form.setConfirmationMessage("Congratulations. You have completed the quiz. Your results will be emailed to you shortly. Please email us at hello@exampapers.io if you require any assistance.");
      form.setDescription(description);
      form.setProgressBar(true);
      form.setShuffleQuestions(true);
      form.setShowLinkToRespondAgain(true);
      form.setCollectEmail(true);

      const item5 = form.addTextItem();
      item5.setTitle('What is your name?')
        .setRequired(true); // mark the question as required if needed

      var section2 = form.addPageBreakItem();
      section2.setTitle(header);

      var questions = Object.values(quiz).filter(item => item.hasOwnProperty("question"));

      // Loop through the questions and add them to the form
      for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        var question = questions[i];
        try {
          var options = question.options.filter(option => option !== null);
          var correctIndex = parseFloat(question.answer) - 1;

          var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
          item.setRequired(true);
          item.setTitle(question.question);
          Logger.log(question.question);

          var choices = [];
          options.forEach(function (option, index) {
            choices.push(
              item.createChoice(option, index === correctIndex)
            );
          });

          shuffleArray(choices);
          item.setChoices(choices).setPoints(1);
          // base.setData("quizzes/" + quizName + "/status", true);
        } catch (error) {
          Logger.log(
            "Error occurred while adding question " +
            question.question +
            ": " +
            error.message
          );
        }
      }

      const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(quizName + " Responses");
      const publishedFormUrl = form.getPublishedUrl();
      const sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
      const range = sheet.getRange(1, 1);
      form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, spreadsheet.getId());
      range.setValue("Responses to " + form.getTitle() + " will be stored in this spreadsheet: " + publishedFormUrl);
      var responseSheetId = form.getDestinationId();
      var responseSheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + responseSheetId + "/edit";

      var formId = form.getId(); // Get the ID of the newly created form
      Logger.log("Form ID: " + formId);
      Logger.log(extractedname);
      Logger.log(publishedFormUrl);
      Logger.log(responseSheetUrl);

      createFormTrigger(formId, extractedname, responseSheetUrl);
    } else {
      Logger.log("Quiz has been created before");
    }
  }
}
```